# PeerGuardian blocks my wifi ip!

Tags: wireless, ip, editing

I’ve tried every thing even the PeerGuardian wiki! What I get it that when it tells me to restart pgl after adding the extra ip addresses the restart fails! When I "start" PeerGuardian is gives me an error saying that the file the wiki told to edit that would fix the ip block then causes both the restart to fail and PeerGuardian!! Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you used the wrong sysntax. Check /var/log/pgl/pglcmd.log for error messages.

Generally it is easiest and safest to just use pglgui and right-click in the log tab on any blocked connection that you want to whitelist.

The decision whether you want to whitelist any IP depends solely on your personal needs. Just don't whitelist simply an IP (or worse: an port) because it annoys you.

Comment: I dont have any errors in that file, but I still cant get online, what should I white list to get back on line?!